# What is a good way of adding multiple secrets in azure keyvault in one go?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have a requirement to store multiple key vault secrets into Azure Key vault all in one go using Azure pipelines.

The problem I have is, I can't use the variables files to load all the secrets and use Set-AzKeyVaultSecret as the variables file resides in the repo. Would you mind letting me know the best way of loading the secrets without leaving any traces of the secrets in the repo? maybe read from a CSV file from a storage blob? Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define these secrets as azure pipelines secret variables. With az cli or powershell task, you can create a loop and load them to azure keyvault.

Of course, as you mentioned, you can use a blob csv file (or any other storage solution) and retrieve it from the code. That's another way as well.